# What is this plant with long thin leaves with serrated edges and spikes of pink flowers?

Tags: identification, weeds

Can anyone identify this plant with long thin leaves with serrated edges and spikes of pink flowers at the tip of the stem? Is it a weed? Getting quite a few growing around my garden and not sure whether to pull them out or not.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Water it.  If it dies, it wasn't a weed.  Alternatively, you could pull it up.  If it grows back, its a weed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is [Stachys palustris](http://species.wikimedia.org/wiki/Stachys_palustris): marsh woundwort or marsh hedgenettle. It is related to wood betony or heal-all ([Stachys officinalis](http://species.wikimedia.org/wiki/Stachys_officinalis)). We have several colonies growing in the wet meadow areas along a local creek. I live in Denmark, where the plant isn't a problem, but it's regarded as a 'noxious weed' in Maine (USA). See http://www.ars-grin.gov/cgi-bin/npgs/html/taxon.pl?312174

Comment: I think you're right, it's certainly spreading like a weed. I suspected as much. Thanks (I live in the UK btw).

Answer (score 4):

Take a leave between two fingers and rub it - then smell your fingers. If it smells minty go and make yourself a tea or a put them into the salad.

It looks to me like a kind of [Mentha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mentha). But it could be something else which it resembles. I'm not sure.

Whether you consider it a weed or not depends on you and your garden-desgin and feelings: Does this plant fit in your garden or not? Do you like it?

In a herb-garden a mentha is welcome.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, doesn't smell minty but I'm fairly ambivalent about it so it can stay for now :)

Comment: Looks like mint to me too. Very invasive and hard to control.

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY that stacks up, it's now growing out of the flowerbed into the lawn

Answer (score 2):

It's a Salvia of some description, not sure which variety, there are so many. Height and spread will help with ID.

Comment: The largest one is about 2' in height, the one pictured is actually the largest one. Whatever it is, they are sprouting a lot, even popping up in the edge of the lawn.

Answer (score 1):

That is [Betony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stachys_officinalis). We have some in our Southern Ontario lawn that escaped from a flower bed. We mow around it, because it's nice, but it sure will spread if you let it. Plenty of [pictures](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=betony&go=&qs=bs&form=QBIR) online you can compare to, to be sure. The leaves of ours do not smell minty at all.

Comment: I'm not sure it is Betony looking at those pictures, the leaves on there look softer/rounder + the flowers look different to me. That said, it is spreading very quickly into our lawn too